# Using Redshift Spectrum with Cloud Formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want to configure a [RedShift Spectrum](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/spectrum/) resource with a Cloud Formation template. What are the CF template parameters to do so?

For example, a normal RedShift can be [templated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html#w2ab2c21c10d843c13) like,

```
myCluster: 
  Type: "AWS::Redshift::Cluster"
  Properties:
    DBName: "mydb"
    MasterUsername: "master"
    MasterUserPassword: 
      Ref: "MasterUserPassword"
    NodeType: "dw.hs1.xlarge"
    ClusterType: "single-node"
    Tags:
      - Key: foo
        Value: bar
```

What is the Spectrum equivalent?

Comment: Can you please provide more details of what you want to "setup"? AWS CloudFormation can launch the database, but it does not run queries *within* the database. Nor can it define tables (for Spectrum or otherwise).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein See edit. I just want the CF template parameters for Spectrum.

Comment: To do what? To create an external schema?

Comment: Exactly what the template in the question does (just applied to Spectrum). No schema or anything. Just an example and links to template documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template looks ok, but there is one more thing to consider which is the IAM role (`IAMRoles` array) that is needed the CF documentation lists this as an additional parameter.

```
myCluster: 
  Type: "AWS::Redshift::Cluster"
  Properties:
    DBName: "mydb"
    MasterUsername: "master"
    MasterUserPassword: 
      Ref: "MasterUserPassword"
    NodeType: "dw.hs1.xlarge"
    ClusterType: "single-node"
    IamRoles:
      - "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/S3Access"
    Tags:
      - Key: foo
        Value: bar
```

The IAM role is needed to talk to the Glue / Athena catalog and authenticate your requests against your data in S3.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift Spectrum is a *feature* of Amazon Redshift.

Simply launch a normal Amazon Redshift cluster and the features of Amazon Redshift Spectrum are available to you.

From [Getting Started with Amazon Redshift Spectrum](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html):

> To use Redshift Spectrum, you need an Amazon Redshift cluster and a SQL client that's connected to your cluster so that you can execute SQL commands.